# update query incrementing value of variable by 2 but should increment by 1 php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
mysql_query("UPDATE neuralnetwork set value= value + 1 WHERE varName='count'");
```

This query is increasing value of count by 2 when executed from php.
But when the same query executed from mysql query window value is incremented by 1.

auto_increment_increment is 1. 
'value' row is of type float.

what can be the reason?

Comment: This is not related to `auto_increment`.  How many rows does it match?

Comment: Odds are that you're executing the query twice

Comment: If you create a PHP page that only does just that query, does it still happen? If not: post the rest of the PHP page, something is executing twice.

Comment: I guess the php script loaded twice, please examine your code

Comment: I would recommend using an IDE with a debugger if you aren't already. It would allow you to step through your code and see what's going on. Would help you track down whether the query is being executed twice.

Comment: The whole code is like this....

<?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
 mysql_select_db("wn2sql", $con);
 
 mysql_query("UPDATE neuralnetwork set `value`= `value` + 1 WHERE varName='count'"); 
 mysql_close($con);
?>

And there is only one row matching the condition in table.

Comment: And yes, when i tried the value to 0.5 then it is increased by 1. It means it is running the query twice but don't know where. I'm just calling mysql_query() function once in the page.

Comment: I tried running the page in firefox and it is working fine but in chrome it is executing twice. can anybody tell me the reason???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not due to your query it  seems OK. Something is wrong in your PHP script or script loaded twice, please do benchmarking and try to find what is going wrong.

Comment: The script is running in chrome twice but in firefox running once.
There were some bugs reported in chromium about that may be those are the issues.